# Echo after Update Query

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to echo Test Closed once the update query has been run. If it fails I would like to echo test not closed.

```
 if (isset($_POST['closetest'])){
       $ts = $_GET["tid"];
       $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE test_set SET isOpen = 0 WHERE id= ?");
       $stmt->bind_param("i", $ts);
       $stmt->execute();

         echo 'Test Closed';

 }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

}
```

Comment: There's a function made especially for that. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: If its executed without errors then `echo test close` else `echo test not closed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a difficult thing to do if you take a look at at [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)

```
if (isset($_POST['closetest']))
{

    $ts = $_GET["tid"];

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE test_set 
                                          SET isOpen = 0 WHERE id= ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $ts);
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    if ( $result === FALSE ) {
        echo 'Test Not closed, in fact the query failed ' . $stmt->error;
    } else {
        echo "Test Closed!";     
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your code like:

```
if (!$stmt->execute()){
    echo "Test Closed!";
}
else{
    echo "Test Not Closed!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

Either check for errors:

```
if(!$stmt->execute()){
    trigger_error("There was an error.... ".$conn->error, E_USER_WARNING);
}
```

or use `mysqli_affected_rows()`

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Object oriented style

> int $mysqli->affected_rows;

Procedural style

> int mysqli_affected_rows ( mysqli $link )

*Returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query.*

Mind you, checking for errors at the same time would be best.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php